# Regex-invalid quantifier error in matching

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regexp using variables as i don't know the specific words

so after placing the variable correctly i got this code

```
var newregxobj="(?=(?<!kbWR"))(?=(?<!none"))>[0-9\.]+<";
```

which i made REGEXP using

```
var re = new RegExp(newregxobj,"g");
```

when I try to use to in matching its shows up an error:

> SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

I've tried to escape almost all quantifier but nothing happens .

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape that double quote in the middle there:

```
"(?=(?<!kbWR\"))(?=(?<!none\"))>[0-9\.]+<";
```

Comment: Interesting, what language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I missed another quote that needed escaping.  Just edited.

Comment: JS i'm then using this code to match from the html string via        var re = new RegExp(newregxobj,"g");
alert(re);
var ip=myString.match(re);

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `"` with `\`, to make it `\"`.

On the other hand, you don't have to escape period inside of `[...]`.

I also recommend to avoid negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` inside of positive lookahead `(?=...)`

---

```
kbWR\")(?<!none\")>[0-9.]+<
```

---

#### Update:

Because you use Javascript and lookbehind is not supported, you must use alternative solution

```
var re = new RegExp("(?!kbWR\"|none\").{5}>[0-9.]+<", "g");
```

Comment: the problem is my string depends on lookbehind

Comment: i'm trying to use match=> var re = new RegExp(newregxobj,"g");after this the error comes

Comment: @RpkRocks - JavaScript **does not support** lookbehind

Comment: @RpkRocks - I have updated my answer with alternative solution. Please remove all your comments above, as they are now irrelevant. Thanks